# how to write/code javascript(mouseover event) using c# methods/ c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, onmouseover

note

- yes client side must be java script but my qustion is not that.
- i am asking that can i use c# language to implement "actions" fired on "click side events" such as mouse over
- the reason for this stupid question is that i remember some syntax of registering functions for particular events of formview, which are call when the event occurs (yes there ispostback involved"
- is something like the above possible for client side events using c# or even vb.net

heres a scrap of what i am trying to ask

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{



    Label3.Text = "this is label three";



    Label3.Attributes.Add("OnMouseOver", "testmouseover()");



}


protected void testmouseover()
{
    Label4.Text = "this is label 4 mouse is working!!";

}
```

Comment: A) Sounds like this is an ASP.NET thing.  B) Sounds like you need to do some AJAX.  I'm not too familiar with ASP.NET, but that's a step in the right direction.

Comment: not se easy man. not so easy...

Comment: What net effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: net effect is all code on the .aspx.cs page, i dont want to go back and forth to html and .cs to manage complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock() have what you need?. Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

That is not possible.

- You can use AJAX, but you cannot use AJAX to directly manipulate the DOM.
- You can use an UpdatePanel, but not (easily) for mouse events.
- You can use [Script#](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp), which converts C# into Javascript.
  However, it would have nothing to do with server-side code

Comment: +1 but will wait before selecting your answer as you sayin not possible! this is the .net framework and the c#!! not possible (

Comment: @user: Correct; it's not possible.  There is no connection between the DOM and the server.  Javascript is, and always will be, an integral part of web development; you'll need to live with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using page methods.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label3.Text = "this is label three";
    Label3.Attributes.Add("OnMouseOver", "testmouseover()");
}

[webmethod]
public static void testmouseover()
{
    // Implement this static method

}
```

and then on client side do this:

```
<script type='javascript'>
function testmouseover()
{
    PageMethods.testmouseover();
}
</script>
```